# Firewall not keeping relay attempts from reaching postfix

Tags: centos, postfix, firewall, webmin

I have a centos-based vps managed with webmin and every once in a while I get a few hundred emails like this one:

```
From: MAILER-DAEMON@mail.<redacted>.com
To: postmaster@<redacted>.com
Subject: Postfix SMTP server: errors from unknown[20.229.210.160]

Transcript of session follows.

 Out: 220 mail.<redacted>.com ESMTP Postfix
 In:  EHLO yupk81.domain
 Out: 250-mail.<redacted>.com
 Out: 250-PIPELINING
 Out: 250-SIZE 30720000
 Out: 250-VRFY
 Out: 250-ETRN
 Out: 250-STARTTLS
 Out: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
 Out: 250-8BITMIME
 Out: 250 DSN
 In:  STARTTLS
 Out: 454 4.7.0 TLS not available due to local problem
 Out: 421 4.4.2 mail.<redacted>.com Error: timeout exceeded
```

Session aborted, reason: timeout

For other details, see the local mail logfile

Here's what I believe are the log entries related to one such email:

```
Jun 10 19:20:46 fla postfix/qmgr[931]: 9CFCD40033: removed
Jun 10 19:21:54 fla postfix/submission/smtpd[29389]: connect from unknown[20.229.210.160]
Jun 10 19:21:54 fla postfix/submission/smtpd[29389]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:127.0.0.1:8891: Connection refused
Jun 10 19:22:07 fla postfix/submission/smtpd[29551]: timeout after STARTTLS from unknown[20.229.210.160]
Jun 10 19:22:07 fla postfix/cleanup[30329]: E0A0840033: message-id=<20220610232207.E0A0840033@mail.<redacted>.com>
Jun 10 19:22:07 fla postfix/qmgr[931]: E0A0840033: from=<double-bounce@mail.<redacted>.com>, size=914, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 10 19:22:07 fla postfix/submission/smtpd[29551]: disconnect from unknown[20.229.210.160]
Jun 10 19:22:09 fla postfix/smtp[30336]: E0A0840033: to=<my_personal_email>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=mail.<redacted>.com [<IP address redacted>]:25, delay=2, delays=0.01/0/0.76/1.3, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4LKcS06tJyz9vNQY)
Jun 10 19:22:09 fla postfix/qmgr[931]: E0A0840033: removed
Jun 10 19:22:18 fla postfix/postfix-script[30470]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/dump
Jun 10 19:22:18 fla postfix/postfix-script[30471]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/dump.txt
```

I set the Linux IPTables Firewall to drop packets coming from the abocve IP address, but postfix keeps sending me those emails from the postmaster account, so the attempts are still reaching postfix. It's driving me mad. Isn't the firewall supposed to stop traffic originating from tha IP address? Why isn't it doing its job?

Thanks!

Edit 2022-06-10 21:25 - Added iptables here (unclear on why the dates listed in the file are all from 2015, as it shows the changes I made today):

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Nov 28 22:24:57 2015
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [28036:5505542]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [27892:10681911]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Nov 28 22:24:57 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Nov 28 22:24:57 2015
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [28036:5505542]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [27892:10681911]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Nov 28 22:24:57 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Nov 28 22:24:57 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1490:86220]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1490:86220]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4732:332455]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4732:332455]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Nov 28 22:24:57 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Nov 28 22:24:57 2015
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [28036:5505542]
:INPUT ACCEPT [28036:5505542]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [27892:10681911]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [27892:10681911]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Nov 28 22:24:57 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Nov 28 22:24:57 2015
*filter
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
# Drop packets from 31.210.20.235
-A INPUT -s 20.229.210.160 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j LOG  --log-prefix "BANDWIDTH_IN:" --log-level 7
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state -m icmp --icmp-type 8 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --dport 22 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --dport 25 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --dport 80 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --dport 443 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o eth0 -j LOG  --log-prefix "BANDWIDTH_OUT:" --log-level 7
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -j LOG  --log-prefix "BANDWIDTH_IN:" --log-level 7
-A FORWARD -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG  --log-prefix "iptables_FORWARD_denied: " --log-level 7
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j LOG  --log-prefix "BANDWIDTH_OUT:" --log-level 7
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG  --log-prefix "iptables_INPUT_denied: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --dport 587 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --dport 465 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
# test
-A INPUT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Nov 28 22:24:57 2015
```

Edit 2022-06-10 22:05 - /var/log/maillog after shutting down and restarting postfix:

```
Jun 10 22:03:23 fla postfix/postfix-script[4257]: stopping the Postfix mail system
Jun 10 22:03:23 fla postfix/master[3818]: terminating on signal 15
Jun 10 22:03:24 fla postfix/postfix-script[4321]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/dump
Jun 10 22:03:24 fla postfix/postfix-script[4322]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/dump.txt
Jun 10 22:03:24 fla postfix/postfix-script[4323]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/<redacted>.pem
Jun 10 22:03:24 fla postfix/postqueue[4341]: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly
Jun 10 22:03:36 fla dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 1 secs): user=<>, rip=<redacted_ip_address>, lip=<redacted_ip_address>, session=<itN0diLhLABqS77J>
Jun 10 22:04:00 fla postfix/postfix-script[4488]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/dump
Jun 10 22:04:00 fla postfix/postfix-script[4489]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/dump.txt
Jun 10 22:04:00 fla postfix/postfix-script[4490]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/<redacted>.pem
Jun 10 22:04:00 fla postfix/postfix-script[4507]: starting the Postfix mail system
Jun 10 22:04:00 fla postfix/master[4509]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Jun 10 22:04:01 fla postfix/postfix-script[4567]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/dump
Jun 10 22:04:01 fla postfix/postfix-script[4568]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/dump.txt
Jun 10 22:04:01 fla postfix/postfix-script[4569]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/<redacted>.pem
```

Comment: Sorry. Just added a copy of iptables.

Comment: Judging from the `Generated .. 2015` comment that file was dumped almost **7 years ago**. You should show your *currently effective* configuration, and run `iptables-restore --test` on the file you attempted to load to figure out why it has not been applied, probably a syntax error.

Comment: iptables-restore --test returns nothing. Does that mean that my iptables file is OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while and despite my attempts at providing the information I was being asked, no one other than user anx seemed to find my problem worthy of providing some assistance. I wish whoever down-voted it to -1 had the decency of explaining why, but that's moot now.

The issue with the few hundred bounces every so often continued to happen and today I got someone (their IP is 20.168.57.26), whose fingers I'd gladly chop myself attempt to use my server as a relay *thousands* of times, which created some other problems for me, so I brute-forced the issue by deleting the postmaster account from the system.

Comment: Hi, please refrain from passive/aggressive text, it dont help to get feedback in the end. On a general advise if you have a box that is more open for relay I tend to advise to use a smarthost in between (some company sell such service), so your MX point to that smarthost, and it do the anti-spam, anti-relay stuff, and you setup your box to only accept mail from that remote smarthost. It's not magic as it imply cost, but it help to keep offender at bay.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have configured a Milter and failed to ensure it is running and accessible, Postfix complains that it cannot connect `connect to Milter service inet:127.0.0.1:8891: Connection refused`. This *could* be a mistake in your firewall configuration as well, as the connection to the Milter is subject to packet filtering.
2. You do not have rules in place to restrict IPs that can be used to access your *submission* service. This may be because you mistakenly only restricted access for first smtp port (25), missing out other ports (465 and/or 587, most likely) you are exposing additional SMTP services on.
3. You have opted in to receive *error* notifications to the postmaster box, but seem to focus on the *connection* attempt. I would not worry much about someone connecting (and presumably ordinarily being refused service as unauthorized anyway), as I would about that attempt just happening to be the occasion for Postfix to notice a configuration problem. This could be *separate* (from 1.) problem in your Postfix configuration that Postfix would have *logged* on startup. Restart Postfix and read the logs.

Comment: The reference to Milter was added to postfix's configuration when I added a dkim record for the domain. I was just following some instructions I found online for that and at the time I was more concerned about outgoing emails being compliant with requirements not to be misconstrued as spam. Since that criteria was met and email has been going out normally, I never bothered to look at the logs, let alone figure out what Milter is.